# Loading header with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on node js with mongoDb. I have one strange problem when loading with header page.

The following code works perfectly

```
var articledetailpage = function (req, res, next) {
Articlepost.find({},function(err,docs){
res.write(loadView('articledetail',{doc:docs}));
next();         
 })

app.get('/articlepage',header,headerhome,articledetailpage,footer);
```

But when i want to pass url parameters dynamically it doesn't load header.

```
 var articledetailpage = function (req, res, next) {
 Articlepost.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,docs){
 res.write(loadView('articledetail',{doc:docs}));
 next();         
 }) 
};
app.get('/articlepage/:id',header,headerhome,articledetailpage,footer);
```

when i run the code with url

```
localhost:3000/articlepage/fetched_id_from_database
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say , the header isn't loaded , you mean you get an error or it's just that the engine doesn't load it at all ? be more specific please.